# Copy ListItems to the DropDownList Items’ ListItemCollection without using a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, html-select

I’m dynamically generating many DropDownList boxes (on an ASP.NET WebForm page) that allows the user to select a value between 0 to 24 from the list. The DropDownList has a ListItemCollection Items property, and I would like to be able to copy ListItems to this collection without having to use a For loop for each DropDownList.

I was initially hoping to create a `List<ListItems>`  with the values of 0-24 with the following code:

```
List<ListItem> listHours = new List<ListItem>();
for (int hr = 0; hr < 25; hr++)
{
    listHours.Add(new ListItem(hr.ToString(), hr.ToString()));
}
```

And then copy this list to each DropDownList.

It appears that you cannot set DropDownList’s Item property (i.e. `myDropDownList.Items = listHours`) since you get the error that “…Items has no setter.”

I can write a function to fill each DropDownList with values 1-24, but that would use a for-loop and take more time.

Is there a way to copy a list of items (be it a `List<ListItems>`, an array of ListItem, etc.) to a DropDownList without having to use a for-loop?

Comment: "and take more time". Why do you think that? How do you think other options work? There's `for` loops behind the scenes everywhere.

Comment: Also, just want to make sure here, but that for loop you have to produce 25 total values. Is that really want you want?

Comment: I have 1070 dynamically generated DropDownList on the page (only shown when needed) that would require 25,680 for-loop iterations to fill all of the DropDownList with 0-24. Currenly it only adds about 2-4 seconds to the page load but I'd like to reduce this if possible.

Comment: As for the second question. Yes that is what we want. Since we are not allowing the user to select minutes we are including both "0" and "24" - which is the same time. So a range could start at 0 and a range can end at 24; but a range would not be allowed to start at 24 or end at 0. Our end time will always be greater than the start time. Also a range 0-0 or 24-24 would also NOT be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking something simliar as Eugene.
Here it is in 1 line:

```
 DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 25).Select(x => new ListItem(x.ToString(), x.ToString())).ToArray());
```

Comment: I've decided to go with this solution. This solution reduced page load time by 25% versus using the for..loop (which was the solution I was using).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddRange method :

```
List<ListItem> listHours = new List<ListItem>();
for (int hr = 0; hr < 25; hr++)
{
     listHours.Add(new ListItem(hr.ToString(), hr.ToString()));
}
myDropDownList.Items.AddRange(listHours.ToArray());
```

Comment: This solution also reduced the page load time by 25%.